# How to access specific attribute from lodash map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

After clicking on a button that uploads tweets to the state of the container.  it takes in the information corresponding to each tweet and creates a state "tweets" is an array that contains each individual tweet and its attributes.  This portion works, as I can see the attributes show up in react web console.

How can I access this tweet's attributes, such as its text attribute?

Here is the map itself

```
      return _.map(tweets, (tweet) => {
        return {
          id: tweet.id_str,
          createdAt: tweet.created_at,
          text: tweet.text
        };
      });
    })
```

I'm somewhat unfamiliar with lodash and I've tried to access with

```
alert( { this.tweets[0].text } )
```

But even that doesn't seem to work.  How do you access lodash map attributes?

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? does the alert pop up empty or is there an error?

Comment: This should return this object correctly. You access attributes with a dot. Also, why would you use lodash' map when there is standard ES6 map function? Ah, you have two returns... What does the first return refer to? Can you save the map result to some variable, and then write that out?

Comment: Did you try to alert without the braces? i.e. `alert(this.tweets[0].text)` Also, when you are running this code, has the `this.tweets` property been initialized?

Comment: The tweets property is initialized after clicking on the uploadTweetsbutton.  Would that play a part?

Comment: What is the exact error that you are getting? Is it something about using something a `null` or `undefined` value?

Comment: getting a syntax error that points to [0]